# How can I optimize this Lua event I made in Friday Night Funkin': Psych Engine?

Tags: optimization, lua, lag

So far I have made this event which is supposed to recreate the events you see in "Lights Down" from [VS impostor V4](https://vsimpostor.com/), where it all goes dark, this is the code:

```
---
--- @param eventName string
--- @param value1 string
--- @param value2 string
---
function onEvent(eventName, value1, value2)
    if eventName == 'lights-out' then
        makeLuaSprite("blackout", "", -1000, -700.0);
        makeGraphic("blackout", 5500, 7500, "000000");
        addLuaSprite("blackout", false);
        triggerEvent("Change Character", "Dad", "itsoutchy lights down");
        triggerEvent("Change Character", "BF", "whitebf");
    end
end
```

However, I'm not sure how I can optimize this, as it freezes for some frames when I use the event. I think it is due to the way Lua sprites are made.

To make the "blackout" sprite not lag when created, I tried making the sprite smaller, but the current size is necessary from what I've tested.

EDIT: I also tried making the sprite when the song first starts using another script, however that didn't stop the lag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're still having this issue I think this should work

```
function oncreate()
    addCharacterToList('itsoutchy lights down', 'dad')
    addCharacterToList('whitebf', 'dad')
end
```

Comment: I had a more detailed explanation written out but I closed the tab by accident and lost it :(